# Gradle Splitting up Testing Tasks with File Structure

Tags: configuration, groovy, gradle, build.gradle

I'm trying to make my tasks run tests in a certain directory.  I was looking at sourceSets, however I inferred that they are useful if you are running outside the test/groovy folder.  All of my tests are within the test/groovy folder.

I've got a set of Geb tests as well as a set of service tests.  I would like to run them both together and independently.  Essentially my tree structure would look like this, being able to run all tests.

```
Test
--gebTest
----firefoxTest
----chromeTest
----ieTest
--servicesTest
----service1Test
----service2Test
----service3Test
----etc.
```

My file structure is as follows:

```
project
-src
--test
---groovy
----com
-----acme
------functional <---where my geb tests sit
------services <---umbrella for services
-------service1 <---each unique service
-------service2
-------service3
-------etc
```

Can anyone lend me a hand.  For the life of me I don't know how Gradle picks what tests to execute.

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: Not sure I completely understand, when you run `gradle test`, it executes using `JUNIT` all the methods in classes that have `@Test` annotation. Each class runs independently. http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test.html , JUNIT example - http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JUnit/article.html

Comment: The problem is that it runs ALL of my tests.  I want to be able to run a task that does functional tests, then another task to run the services tests.

Comment: :) In which case you are looking for this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9606904/how-to-run-junit-testsuites-from-gradle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SourceSets are indeed a solution to your problem, but I notice you only differentiate your tests by their package names. I'm not sure but that may prove problematic with source sets.

Personally I would prefer a directory structure like this anyway

```
src
-test
--groovy
---functional
----com etc
---services
----com etc
```

However, if you are attached to your current structure then take a look at Gradle's test filtering support, which will allow you to filter by package name.

http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/java_plugin.html#sec:java_test

Comment: I had to upgrade from 1.9, but includeTestsMatching() is exactly what I wanted.  Thank you